# R: how to drop down sundays and saturdays from a tibble

Tags: r, datetime, tibble

I have a database as a tibble that record the amount of products sold each day, with different kinds of products. I would like to exclude saturdays and sundays to have the number of products sold during a standard business week. The weekday parameter has been created using the command "make_date", so it is a date-time.
 I've tried with a for cycle without success:

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){
      if(Data$weekday[i] == "saturday"){
      Data = Data[-i,]}
    }
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you tried `filter()`?  Like `filter(Data, weekday != "saturday")`.  Or, for both days, `filter(Data, !weekday %in% c("sunday", "saturday"))`.

Comment: A for loop is not idiomatic R programming in this particular case. You should rather use some vectorized function. Do you have sample data to provide? That would greatly help.

Comment: In particular, the reason this is probably not working is that you are changing `Data`'s shape inside a loop where the number of loops depends on it. use `dplyr::filter` as suggested instead.

Comment: Thank you! With filter() works well!
Thanks to all!